# Crawling & parsing results of querying google-like search engine

Tags: java, parsing, web-crawler, jsoup

I have to write parser in Java (my first html parser by this way). For now I'm using jsoup library and I think it is very good solution for my problem.

Main goal is to get some information from Google Scholar (h-index, numbers of publications, years of scientific carier). I know how to parse html with 10 people, like this:

http://scholar.google.pl/citations?mauthors=Cracow+University+of+Economics&hl=pl&view_op=search_authors

```
for( Element element : htmlDoc.select("a[href*=/citations?user") ){
    if( element.hasText() ) {
        String findUrl = element.absUrl("href");
        pagesToVisit.add(findUrl);
    }
}
```

BUT I need to find information about all of scientists from asked university. How to do that? I was thinking about getting url from button, which is guiding us to next 10 results, like that:

```
Elements elem = htmlDoc.getElementsByClass("gs_btnPR");
String nextUrl = elem.attr("onclick");
```

But I get url like that:

```
citations?view_op\x3dsearch_authors\x26hl\x3dpl\x26oe\x3dLatin2\x26mauthors\x3dAGH+University+of+Science+and+Technology\x26after_author\x3dslQKAC78__8J\x26astart\x3d10
```

I have to translate `\x` signs and add that site to my "toVisit" sites? Or it is a better idea inside jsoup library or mayby in other library? Please let me know! I don't have any other idea, how to parse something like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to translate \x signs and add that site to my "toVisit" sites...I don't have any other idea, how to parse something like this...

The `\xAA` is [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) encoded [ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). For instance `\x3d` is `=`, and `\x26` is `&`. These values can be converted using `Integer.parseInt` with radix set to 16.

```
char c = (char)Integer.parseInt("\\x3d", 16);
System.out.println(c);
```

If you need to decode these values without a 3rd party library, you can do so using regular expressions. For example, using the String supplied in your question:

```
String st = "citations?view_op\\x3dsearch_authors\\x26hl\\x3dpl\\x26oe\\x3dLatin2\\x26mauthors\\x3dAGH+University+of+Science+and+Technology\\x26after_author\\x3dslQKAC78__8J\\x26astart\\x3d10";
System.out.println("Before Decoding: " + st);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})");
Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
while ( m.find() ){
    String c = Character.toString((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16));
    st = st.replaceAll("\\" + m.group(0), c);
    m = p.matcher("After Decoding: " + st);//optional, but added for clarity as st has changed
}
System.out.println(st);
```

Comment: Because = and & was only characters in hexadecimal encoding i used simple solution (I don't know it is faster than you, but is really simplier ).

Extracting all parts starting with \x would be more ellegant and universal I guess. Is it a good reason why I couldn't use my short way? :)

 `nextPageUrl = nextPageUrl.replace("\\x3d", "=").replace("\\x26", "&");`

Comment: Short way works in principle, as long as the server response is guaranteed (in other words, the code doesn't account for the possibility that the server won't spit out an unrecognized encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You currently get a URL like this using your code:

`citations?view_op\x3dsearch_authors\x26hl\x3dpl\x26oe\x3dLatin2\x26mauthors\x3dAGH+University+of+Science+and+Technology\x26after_author\x3dQPQwAJz___8J\x26astart\x3d10`

You have to extract that bold part (using a regex), and use that to construct the URL for getting the next page of search results, which looks like this:

`scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=plmauthors=Cracow+University+of+Economic&after_author=QPQwAJz___8J`

You can then get that next page from this URL and parse using Jsoup, and repeat for getting all the next remaining pages.

Will put together some example code later.